# How to connect domain name to nodejs application in Windows Server with IIS?

Tags: node.js, iis, server, windows-server

I need to connect a domain name with my **nodejs application**. I used **Amazon aws ec2** instance and I run locally node project.

How can I connect my domain name to my nodejs application? I'm using a Windows Server with IIS.

Comment: it is unclear to me if you are trying to reach your node instance on ec2 from your computer. In which case it is only a matter of determining ec2 host, node port and AWS security to let you through

Answer (score 0):

## Using Linux Server

You can do this using **[Nginx Proxy Pass](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html)**.

### First, install Nginx for your distribution

**Ubuntu**: `sudo apt-get install nginx`
**Fedora/Centos**: `yum install nginx`

### Second, configure your Nginx vhost

**Edit your config** `sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/default`
add these lines at the very bottom of your file:

```
server {
  listen 80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
  #listen [::]:80 default ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6
  root /your_nodejs_app_directory;
  server_name your_domain_name.ex;
  location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:7195;
  }
}
```

**remember to change:**
`/your_nodejs_app_directory` with your nodejs app directory
`your_domain_name.ex` with a domain name that point to your server
`:7195` with your NodeJS application port

**reboot Nginx**

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

Note that, if you are using a **RedHat based distribution (like Fedora and Centos)**, you need to do:

```
/etc/init.d/nginx restart
```

or

```
/etc/init.d/nginx reload
```

to reboot Nginx.
now you can see your **NodeJS** application **by visiting your_domain_name.ex**

## Using Windows Server

**IIS** have a **method nginx-like** named **ARR** ([Application Request Routing](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing)).
See documentation [Here.](http://blogs.iis.net/wonyoo/application-request-routing-arr-as-a-reverse-proxy)

Comment: ubuntu is complusory?? can windows server connected with nodejs?

Comment: No, you can use Windows Server with IIS with Application Request Routing http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing

Comment: I've added Windows Server solution to my answer.

Comment: Hi @Mirko, i checked ARR but i find  aws service elastic beanstalk for node project, so thanks your support.